# Adding to a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

```
def countFrequency(L):
    fdict = {}
    for x in range(0, len(L)):
        for key, value in fdict:
            if L[x] == fdict[str(x)]:
                value = value + 1
            else:
                fdict[L[x]] = 1
    return fdict
```

I'm trying to count the frequency of occurrences of a particular symbol in a given string and create a dictionary out of this. For some reason, the function just returns an empty dictionary. I think the problem arises with adding a new value to the dictionary, but not sure how to troubleshoot it/fix it.

```
input: countFrequency('MISSISSIPPI')
output: {}
```

Comment: `for key, value in fdict:` your dict is empty. Also why do you think you need a for loop to add elements to a dict?

Comment: I'm checking to see if that letter is already in the dictionary, and if so, I would just add one to the value.

Comment: If you're not writing this for homework, I'd strongly recommend using `collections.Counter` rather than writing your own code to do the same thing. Python comes with batteries included! Your whole function body could be `return collections.Counter(L)`.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain the `for` loop. You aren't even using `key` (and the way you are trying to use `value` is wrong logically)

Comment: You could avoid all this by using the [`collections.Counter()` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
def countFrequency(L):
    fdict = {}
    for x in range(0, len(L)):
        if str(L[x]) in fdict.keys():
           fdict[str(L[x])] = fdict[str(L[x])] + 1
        else:
           fdict[str(L[x])] = 1
    return fdict
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in the inner loop:

```
        if L[x] == fdict[str(x)]:
            value = value + 1
        else:
            fdict[L[x]] = 1
```

is unreachable, because the dictionary is empty initally, and hence you will never add any value to `fdict`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it likes this:

```
def countFrequency(L):
    fdict = {}
    for symbol in L: #gets each letter in l
        if symbol in fdict: #check if dhe dictionary already has an value for the symbol
            fdict[symbol] += 1
        else:
            fdict[symbol] = 1
    return fdic
```

Answer (score 0):

Another issue is that the value `value` is never assigned to anything or used, so even if we were to go through the loop we would never increment a value in the dictionary.